# What the C# equivalent of "mklink /J"?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, mklink

I know how to create a symbolic link in windows in a .bat script:

```
mklink /J <LinkPath> <OriginalResourcePath>
```

How to do the same thing in C# ?

I've not been happy with the googling, because i'm a beginner in C# and I probably don't use the right terms. Anybody can indicate the API to use please ?

Comment: http://web3.codeproject.com/Articles/15633/Manipulating-NTFS-Junction-Points-in-NET

Comment: Do you really want to create a junction (hence the `/J` switch to `mklink`)? From the accepted answer it looks you were actually looking for a symbolic link instead (invoke `mklink` without any option).

Comment: Here's a Windows Forms app that uses it. https://github.com/robwil/DropPrefs. Look in the Code Behind file -> MainForm.cs

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Warning**: The question is not clear as it refers to **symbolic links** but at the same time refers to the **/J** switch that is used to create a junction. This answer refers to "how to create a symbolic link in c#" (without the /J). Instead, For creating **junctions**, please refer to [In .NET, how do I Create a Junction in NTFS, as opposed to a Symlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400549/in-net-how-do-i-create-a-junction-in-ntfs-as-opposed-to-a-symlink).

This is how symbolic links can be created:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(
        string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, SymbolicLink dwFlags);

        enum SymbolicLink
        {
            File = 0,
            Directory = 1
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string symbolicLink = @"c:\bar.txt";
            string fileName = @"c:\temp\foo.txt";

            using (var writer = File.CreateText(fileName))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Hello World");
            }

            CreateSymbolicLink(symbolicLink, fileName, SymbolicLink.File);
        }
    }
}
```

This will create a symbolic link file called bar.txt on the C:-drive which links to the foo.txt text file stored in the C:\temp directory.

Comment: thanks for the code sample, but I validated isrog answers because his link provides more information, and I just asked for a pointer. I upvoted your answer too because it's still a good answer.

Comment: Noted, but don't think follow this link answers are SO's purpose. Those links might die anytime. Want users that get here to still have an answer. Not a possible dead link.

Comment: true, I'll think about think next time. Though i usually use links only to very stable places like MSDN of official Javadoc

Comment: Is this really the answer? `mklink /J` creates a (directory) junction. `CreateSymbolicLink` creates a symbolic link (to a file or directory). I think the real answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1400549/21567). Or the question was "inaccurate", since the OP accepted this answer.

Comment: If you're running this program in IIS or other environments, make sure the user account has [permission to create symbolic links](http://superuser.com/a/105381/45163) (Local Security Policy > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Create symbolic links). This confounded me for a while.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. This creates a symbolic link which is different than a junction. Here is a project that has the PInvoke signatures for creating junctions: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15633/Manipulating-NTFS-Junction-Points-in-NET

Comment: @Christophe King: He passed the /J option in his question, but he clearly stated he wanted to created a symbolic link, not a junction.

Comment: My edit is wrong, just disapprove it. Can't believe SO can't let you cancel your edit...

Comment: @jw_ It's OK now. Thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a project that has the PInvoke signatures for creating junctions: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15633/Manipulating-NTFS-Junction-Points-in-NET. The code is copied below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace Util {
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to NTFS junction points in .Net.
    /// </summary>
    public static class JunctionPoint {
        /// <summary>
        /// The file or directory is not a reparse point.
        /// </summary>
        private const int ERROR_NOT_A_REPARSE_POINT = 4390;

        /// <summary>
        /// The reparse point attribute cannot be set because it conflicts with an existing attribute.
        /// </summary>
        private const int ERROR_REPARSE_ATTRIBUTE_CONFLICT = 4391;

        /// <summary>
        /// The data present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.
        /// </summary>
        private const int ERROR_INVALID_REPARSE_DATA = 4392;

        /// <summary>
        /// The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.
        /// </summary>
        private const int ERROR_REPARSE_TAG_INVALID = 4393;

        /// <summary>
        /// There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point.
        /// </summary>
        private const int ERROR_REPARSE_TAG_MISMATCH = 4394;

        /// <summary>
        /// Command to set the reparse point data block.
        /// </summary>
        private const int FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT = 0x000900A4;

        /// <summary>
        /// Command to get the reparse point data block.
        /// </summary>
        private const int FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT = 0x000900A8;

        /// <summary>
        /// Command to delete the reparse point data base.
        /// </summary>
        private const int FSCTL_DELETE_REPARSE_POINT = 0x000900AC;

        /// <summary>
        /// Reparse point tag used to identify mount points and junction points.
        /// </summary>
        private const uint IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT = 0xA0000003;

        /// <summary>
        /// This prefix indicates to NTFS that the path is to be treated as a non-interpreted
        /// path in the virtual file system.
        /// </summary>
        private const string NonInterpretedPathPrefix = @"\??\";

        [Flags]
        private enum EFileAccess : uint {
            GenericRead = 0x80000000,
            GenericWrite = 0x40000000,
            GenericExecute = 0x20000000,
            GenericAll = 0x10000000,
        }

        [Flags]
        private enum EFileShare : uint {
            None = 0x00000000,
            Read = 0x00000001,
            Write = 0x00000002,
            Delete = 0x00000004,
        }

        private enum ECreationDisposition : uint {
            New = 1,
            CreateAlways = 2,
            OpenExisting = 3,
            OpenAlways = 4,
            TruncateExisting = 5,
        }

        [Flags]
        private enum EFileAttributes : uint {
            Readonly = 0x00000001,
            Hidden = 0x00000002,
            System = 0x00000004,
            Directory = 0x00000010,
            Archive = 0x00000020,
            Device = 0x00000040,
            Normal = 0x00000080,
            Temporary = 0x00000100,
            SparseFile = 0x00000200,
            ReparsePoint = 0x00000400,
            Compressed = 0x00000800,
            Offline = 0x00001000,
            NotContentIndexed = 0x00002000,
            Encrypted = 0x00004000,
            Write_Through = 0x80000000,
            Overlapped = 0x40000000,
            NoBuffering = 0x20000000,
            RandomAccess = 0x10000000,
            SequentialScan = 0x08000000,
            DeleteOnClose = 0x04000000,
            BackupSemantics = 0x02000000,
            PosixSemantics = 0x01000000,
            OpenReparsePoint = 0x00200000,
            OpenNoRecall = 0x00100000,
            FirstPipeInstance = 0x00080000
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER {
            /// <summary>
            /// Reparse point tag. Must be a Microsoft reparse point tag.
            /// </summary>
            public uint ReparseTag;

            /// <summary>
            /// Size, in bytes, of the data after the Reserved member. This can be calculated by:
            /// (4 * sizeof(ushort)) + SubstituteNameLength + PrintNameLength + 
            /// (namesAreNullTerminated ? 2 * sizeof(char) : 0);
            /// </summary>
            public ushort ReparseDataLength;

            /// <summary>
            /// Reserved; do not use. 
            /// </summary>
            public ushort Reserved;

            /// <summary>
            /// Offset, in bytes, of the substitute name string in the PathBuffer array.
            /// </summary>
            public ushort SubstituteNameOffset;

            /// <summary>
            /// Length, in bytes, of the substitute name string. If this string is null-terminated,
            /// SubstituteNameLength does not include space for the null character.
            /// </summary>
            public ushort SubstituteNameLength;

            /// <summary>
            /// Offset, in bytes, of the print name string in the PathBuffer array.
            /// </summary>
            public ushort PrintNameOffset;

            /// <summary>
            /// Length, in bytes, of the print name string. If this string is null-terminated,
            /// PrintNameLength does not include space for the null character. 
            /// </summary>
            public ushort PrintNameLength;

            /// <summary>
            /// A buffer containing the unicode-encoded path string. The path string contains
            /// the substitute name string and print name string.
            /// </summary>
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 0x3FF0)]
            public byte[] PathBuffer;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, uint dwIoControlCode,
            IntPtr InBuffer, int nInBufferSize,
            IntPtr OutBuffer, int nOutBufferSize,
            out int pBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
            string lpFileName,
            EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
            EFileShare dwShareMode,
            IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
            ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
            EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
            IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a junction point from the specified directory to the specified target directory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Only works on NTFS.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="targetDir">The target directory to create</param>
        /// <param name="sourceDir">The source directory to alias</param>
        /// <param name="overwrite">If true overwrites an existing reparse point or empty directory</param>
        /// <exception cref="IOException">Thrown when the junction point could not be created or when
        /// an existing directory was found and <paramref name="overwrite" /> if false</exception>
        public static void Create(string sourceDir, string targetDir, bool overwrite) {
            sourceDir = Path.GetFullPath(sourceDir);

            if (!Directory.Exists(sourceDir))
                throw new IOException($"Source path does not exist or is not a directory.");

            if (Directory.Exists(targetDir))
                throw new IOException($"Directory '{targetDir}' already exists.");

            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);

            using (SafeFileHandle handle = OpenReparsePoint(targetDir, EFileAccess.GenericWrite)) {
                byte[] sourceDirBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(NonInterpretedPathPrefix + Path.GetFullPath(sourceDir));

                REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER reparseDataBuffer = new REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER();

                reparseDataBuffer.ReparseTag = IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT;
                reparseDataBuffer.ReparseDataLength = (ushort)(sourceDirBytes.Length + 12);
                reparseDataBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset = 0;
                reparseDataBuffer.SubstituteNameLength = (ushort)sourceDirBytes.Length;
                reparseDataBuffer.PrintNameOffset = (ushort)(sourceDirBytes.Length + 2);
                reparseDataBuffer.PrintNameLength = 0;
                reparseDataBuffer.PathBuffer = new byte[0x3ff0];
                Array.Copy(sourceDirBytes, reparseDataBuffer.PathBuffer, sourceDirBytes.Length);

                int inBufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(reparseDataBuffer);
                IntPtr inBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(inBufferSize);

                try {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(reparseDataBuffer, inBuffer, false);

                    int bytesReturned;
                    bool result = DeviceIoControl(handle.DangerousGetHandle(), FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT,
                        inBuffer, sourceDirBytes.Length + 20, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);

                    if (!result)
                        ThrowLastWin32Error($"Unable to create junction point '{sourceDir}' -> '{targetDir}'.");
                } finally {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inBuffer);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes a junction point at the specified source directory along with the directory itself.
        /// Does nothing if the junction point does not exist.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Only works on NTFS.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="junctionPoint">The junction point path</param>
        public static void Delete(string junctionPoint) {
            if (!Directory.Exists(junctionPoint)) {
                if (File.Exists(junctionPoint))
                    throw new IOException("Path is not a junction point.");

                return;
            }

            using (SafeFileHandle handle = OpenReparsePoint(junctionPoint, EFileAccess.GenericWrite)) {
                REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER reparseDataBuffer = new REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER();

                reparseDataBuffer.ReparseTag = IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT;
                reparseDataBuffer.ReparseDataLength = 0;
                reparseDataBuffer.PathBuffer = new byte[0x3ff0];

                int inBufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(reparseDataBuffer);
                IntPtr inBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(inBufferSize);
                try {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(reparseDataBuffer, inBuffer, false);

                    int bytesReturned;
                    bool result = DeviceIoControl(handle.DangerousGetHandle(), FSCTL_DELETE_REPARSE_POINT,
                        inBuffer, 8, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);

                    if (!result)
                        ThrowLastWin32Error("Unable to delete junction point.");
                } finally {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inBuffer);
                }

                try {
                    Directory.Delete(junctionPoint);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new IOException("Unable to delete junction point.", ex);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified path exists and refers to a junction point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The junction point path</param>
        /// <returns>True if the specified path represents a junction point</returns>
        /// <exception cref="IOException">Thrown if the specified path is invalid
        /// or some other error occurs</exception>
        public static bool Exists(string path) {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                return false;

            using (SafeFileHandle handle = OpenReparsePoint(path, EFileAccess.GenericRead)) {
                string target = InternalGetTarget(handle);
                return target != null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the target of the specified junction point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Only works on NTFS.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="junctionPoint">The junction point path</param>
        /// <returns>The target of the junction point</returns>
        /// <exception cref="IOException">Thrown when the specified path does not
        /// exist, is invalid, is not a junction point, or some other error occurs</exception>
        public static string GetTarget(string junctionPoint) {
            using (SafeFileHandle handle = OpenReparsePoint(junctionPoint, EFileAccess.GenericRead)) {
                string target = InternalGetTarget(handle);
                if (target == null)
                    throw new IOException("Path is not a junction point.");

                return target;
            }
        }

        private static string InternalGetTarget(SafeFileHandle handle) {
            int outBufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER));
            IntPtr outBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(outBufferSize);

            try {
                int bytesReturned;
                bool result = DeviceIoControl(handle.DangerousGetHandle(), FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT,
                    IntPtr.Zero, 0, outBuffer, outBufferSize, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);

                if (!result) {
                    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    if (error == ERROR_NOT_A_REPARSE_POINT)
                        return null;

                    ThrowLastWin32Error("Unable to get information about junction point.");
                }

                REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER reparseDataBuffer = (REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER)
                    Marshal.PtrToStructure(outBuffer, typeof(REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER));

                if (reparseDataBuffer.ReparseTag != IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT)
                    return null;

                string targetDir = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(reparseDataBuffer.PathBuffer,
                    reparseDataBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset, reparseDataBuffer.SubstituteNameLength);

                if (targetDir.StartsWith(NonInterpretedPathPrefix))
                    targetDir = targetDir.Substring(NonInterpretedPathPrefix.Length);

                return targetDir;
            } finally {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(outBuffer);
            }
        }

        private static SafeFileHandle OpenReparsePoint(string reparsePoint, EFileAccess accessMode) {
            SafeFileHandle reparsePointHandle = new SafeFileHandle(CreateFile(reparsePoint, accessMode,
                EFileShare.Read | EFileShare.Write | EFileShare.Delete,
                IntPtr.Zero, ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting,
                EFileAttributes.BackupSemantics | EFileAttributes.OpenReparsePoint, IntPtr.Zero), true);

            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0)
                ThrowLastWin32Error("Unable to open reparse point.");

            return reparsePointHandle;
        }

        private static void ThrowLastWin32Error(string message) {
            throw new IOException(message, Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this in my VS2012, I see the following highlighted error for the declaration for CreateSymbolicLink(): 
The type or namespace name 'SymbolicLink' could not be found

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using .NET 6 or greater this has been simplified a great deal and is now part of the framework.

```
using System.IO;

private void MyMethod(string source, string target) 
{
    // Create symbolic link for directory (answers this question)
    Directory.CreateSymbolicLink(source, target);

    // Create symbolic link for file (additional reference)
    File.CreateSymbolicLink(source, target);
}
```

Comment: Add `File.CreateSymbolicLink`

Answer (score 1):

Another way it to use mklink. It turns out that mklink is an internal command so you need cmd.exe to call it:

```
var psi=new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"," /C mklink \""+link_name+"\" \""+ target_name + "\"");
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit();
```

You can add /J or /d etc as you need.

ref: [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: spawning a new process for this is much more costly than simply calling the correct API