# How to mount a hard drive to a folder using C#?

Tags: c#, system, mount

I'm looking for a way to mount the root directory (C:/) into a folder in another drive (D:/). 
I know of methods to do it from Powershell and Diskpart.
Is there any way to do that from C# without using Powershell?

Comment: Which command do you mean specifically - `mklink /d` ? Or something else? If you tell us exactly what you're trying to replicate that would be useful please.

Comment: This sounds like a 'symbolic link'. See this answer on how to make one https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156870/12342238